# Access to State Class field in another widget's build method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, var

There is such a class

```
class ProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final double size;
  final String text;
  final String textSize;
  ProgressBar({Key? key, required this.size, required this.text, required this.textSize}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProgressBarState createState() => _ProgressBarState();
}

class _ProgressBarState extends State<ProgressBar>  with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<double> animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(
        seconds: 5,
      ),
    );

    animation = Tween<double>(
      begin: 0,
      end: widget.size,
    ).animate(CurvedAnimation(parent: _controller, curve: Curves.easeInOut))
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });

    _controller.forward();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ThemeData theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, top: 12, bottom: 12),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text(widget.text, style: theme.textTheme.bodyText1!.copyWith(fontSize: 14, color: theme.colorScheme.primary)),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 6),
            child: LinearProgressIndicator(
              value: _controller.value,
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
            Text('${animation.value.toStringAsFixed(2)} Мб из ${widget.textSize} Мб', style: theme.textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(color: Color(0xff8F92A1), fontSize: 12)),
            Text('Загрузка...', style: theme.textTheme.bodyText2!.copyWith(color: Color(0xff8F92A1), fontSize: 12)),
          ],)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to use 'animation' in another class.

```
child: ListView.separated(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Divider(color: Color(0xffF3F6F8)),
                  itemCount: items.length + 1,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (index == 0) {
                      return _rowAdd();
                    }
                    return animation.isCompleted ? ProgressBar(size: items[index - 1].sizeFile, text: items[index - 1].nameFile, textSize: items[index - 1].sizeFile.toStringAsFixed(2),) :
                      Padding(
                   ...
                    );
```

How to do it correctly? This is a temporary crutch. In general, my file_picker adds data to the Item class and I need an empty CallBack to come with each file, and temporarily put a timeout for animation in it, but I do not know how to do it yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand what exactly you mean but i try to help:

you want to make a call back from another class? use this :

let say i want to make call back data as string :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef void StringCallback(String value);

class Example extends StatefulWidget {

  final StringCallback callback;
  
  const Example({Key key, this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        getString();
      },
    );
  }
  
  getString(){
    // This is the Data i need from this class:
    String data = "Data I need";
   setState(() {
     widget.callback(data);
   }); 
  }
  
}
```

in another class you can use that like this :

```
Widget testTheCallbackInAnotherClass(){
    return Example(
      callback: (value){
        setState(() {
          final dataIgetFromAnotherClass = value;
          print(dataIgetFromAnotherClass);
        });
      },
    );
  }
```

you can even call all the function in another class like this :

first make a key for example class state

```
GlobalKey<_ExampleState> _key = GlobalKey<_ExampleState>();
```

then call the function :

```
String dataIneedFromExampleClass = _key.currentState.getString();
```

hope its help you